# Get colored texts within HTML code

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing

I have a Html code and I want to Convert it to plain text but keep only colored text tags.
for example:
when I have below Html:

```
<body>

This is a <b>sample</b> html text.
<p align="center" style="color:#ff9999">this is only a sample<p>
....
and some other tags...
</body>
</html>
```

I want the output:

```
this is a sample html text.
<#ff9999>this is only a sample<>
....
and some other tags...
```

Comment: what is the code you have written to achieve this

Comment: thanx, not specified code. plain text with color name tags.

Comment: but you need to write some code to parse the code , right ?

Comment: @Ali.M - Satya means what are you using to even try to pull this off? Jquery? PHP? RegEx?

Comment: Also, you want to replace `<p>` by `<>`, but `<b>` by nothing?

Comment: yes, I want to replace colors to custom tag only and remove other html tags. I want to do it with C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use parser to parse HTML like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), and use regular expressions to find the `color` value in attributes.

First, find all the nodes that contain `style` attribute with `color` defined in it by using xpath:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectNodes("//*[contains(@style, 'color')]")
    .ToArray();
```

Then the simplest regex to match a color value: `(?<=color:\s*)#?\w+`.

```
var colorRegex = new Regex(@"(?<=color:\s*)#?\w+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Then iterate through these nodes and if there is a regex match, replace the inner html of the node with html encoded tags (you'll understand why a little bit later):

```
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    var style = node.Attributes["style"].Value;
    if (colorRegex.IsMatch(style))
    {
        var color = colorRegex.Match(style).Value;
        node.InnerHtml =
            HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<" + color + ">") +
            node.InnerHtml +
            HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("</" + color + ">");
    }
}
```

And finally get the inner text of the document and perform html decoding on it (this is because inner text strips all the tags):

```
var txt = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(doc.DocumentNode.InnerText);
```

This should return something like this:

```
This is a sample html text.
<#ff9999>this is only a sample</#ff9999>
....
and some other tags...
```

Of course you could improve it for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do it using regular expressions but... [You should not parse (X)HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

The first regexp I came with to solve the problem is:

```
<p(\w|\s|[="])+color:(#([0-9a-f]{6}|[0-9a-f]{3}))">(\w|\s)+</p>
```

Group 5th will be the hex (3 or 6 hexadecimals) colour and group 6th will be the text inside the tag.

Obviously, it's not the best solution as I'm not a regexp master and obviously it needs some testing and probably generalisation... But still it's a good point to start with.

Comment: thanks, but it won't work. I am working more with regex to find out a solutin with it.